# Error installing Nvidia proprietary driver on Fedora 18

Tags: installation, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, graphics

I'm trying to install the Nvidia proprietary driver (Geforce 525M) but I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'. This is most likely
>       because the kernel module was built using the wrong kernel source
>       files.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files
>       for your kernel; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be sure you
>       have the 'kernel-source' rpm installed.  If you know the correct
>       kernel source files are installed, you may specify the kernel source
>       path with the '--kernel-source-path' commandline option

Comment: not a programming questions. try superuser.

Comment: @MarcB sorry i will move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the `nvidia-installer` where to find the kernel source you just downloaded is. You can do this by doing exactly what the error is telling you.

1. Locate where the yum installed the kernel source. It's normally somwhere like `/usr/src/linux-2.6.33`
2. `./nvidia-installer --kernel-source-path=/usr/src/linux-2.6.33`

Post your results. Good luck.

Comment: when I excute this commande because When I excute this commande at shell I got `./nvidia-installer: No such file or folder with this name`

Comment: You're in the wrong directory. Go back to the directory you were in, and then re-execute the command.

Comment: I'm in the directory where I have puted the `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-310.32` install File. exactly in `usr\lib\modules`.

Comment: I have updated the post please check it.